# How to build a json file and extract data values from it in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have excel sheet which i need to build the json file. i have build a sample file. but i am unable to proceed with that json file and extract the data from it.

```
[{
   "Material thickness": "10 Mil",        
   "Width": 8,
   "height": 8,
   "Price": "8.76",
   "Quantity":1
},
{
   "Material thickness": "7 Mil",        
   "Width": 8,
   "height": 12,
   "Price": "10.52",
   "Quantity":1
}
]

jQuery.getJSON( siteURL+"/prices.json", function( data ) {
  jQuery.each(data, function (index, value) {
    console.log(index);
    console.log(value);
    console.log(data[index].Material thickness);                             
  });                           
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the [`dot`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Dot_notation) notation when your key contains a space.

> The property accessed with a *dot* notation must be a sequence of alphanumerical characters, also including the underscore ("_") and dollar sign ("$"), that cannot start with a number

Use the [`bracket`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation) notation instead :

```
data[index]['Material thickness']
```

```js
var data = [{
    "Material thickness": "10 Mil",
    "Width": 8,
    "height": 8,
    "Price": "8.76",
    "Quantity": 1
  },
  {
    "Material thickness": "7 Mil",
    "Width": 8,
    "height": 12,
    "Price": "10.52",
    "Quantity": 1
  }
];

$.each(data, function(index, value) {

  //console.log(index);
  //console.log(value);
  console.log(data[index]['Material thickness']);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: getting error {
  "message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 13,
  "colno": 9
}

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
console.log(data[index]["Material thickness"]);
```